# Data Transformation or algorithm for prediction of data between 0 and 1

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, algorithms

I am trying to predict a time series where every data point is a percentage value between 0 and 1. Most data points are either 1 and few below 0.5. In such a case what could be suitable data transformation or an algorithm that can be used for prediction purposes. The plot below shows the data that I have.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help : [Beta Regression for time series analysis of bounded data, with application to Canada Google® flu trends](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3533.pdf)

From the abstract : *Bounded time series consisting of rates or proportions are often encountered in applications. This manuscript proposes a practical
approach to analyze bounded time series.*

And it comes with the [GCMR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gcmr/gcmr.pdf) package.